# Python - removing ASCII Quote in variable string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to insert a variable string using ascii conversion:

```
strings = ['a','b']
for string in strings:
    print ('print this: %a, and be done' % (string))
```

This prints

```
print this: 'a', and be done
print this: 'b', and be done
```

But I don't want the quote (') to show up in the string. Is there a simple way to remove? I want the output to be as follows:

```
print this: a, and be done
print this: b, and be done
```

Note, I need to continue using the %a method for my use case. Can not switch to {} .format method.

Comment: So you want `%s` instead of `%a`?

Comment: Normally yes, but I want the ASCII conversion to remain.

Comment: "ASCII conversion" such as ?

Comment: from built-in types page (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), %s converts using str() fuction, %a converts using ascii() function. I need an ascii output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old `%` formatting is clunky and hard to use. Consider switching to using the `.format` method, like so:

```
strings = ['a', 'b']
for string in strings:
    print('print this: {}, and be done'.format(string))
```

This inserts the `str` representation of `string`, as you want. If you have Python 3.6, you can even use the literal version

```
strings = ['a', 'b']
for string in strings:
    print(f'print this: {string}, and be done')
```

Comment: See comment above, need python to use ascii function for conversion.

Comment: @JeffSaltfist Note that the output of `ascii()` is a unicode `str`, not `bytes`. If the above method is not sufficient for you, please elaborate on what exactly you wish for the code to do.

Comment: I would like my output to be in unicode string, but without the (') included around my string. The {}.format method will not work for my current task.

Comment: Basically just want to figure out how to remove the ' that is placed around the variable string while still using %a

Comment: The answer does what you want.

Comment: Then you could do `print('...' + ('%a' % string)[1:-1] + '...')`, but that's just silly.

Comment: Silly, but it was what I needed. Your answer will work for my general comment as well so I gave the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode with `unicode-escape` and decode back to a string:

```
hex_escaped = string.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')
print('print this: %s, and be done' % (hex_escaped,))
```

Comment: This looks interesting, will test.

Comment: @JeffSaltfist: Did you want `'` escaped when `"` is present?